# Android - Proper way to manipulate (move, delete, etc) Image files

Tags: android, mediastore

I am planning to build an app to manipulate (by manipulation I mean moving, deleting or archiving them to a location. Not editing the images) the image files which are stored in the android based phone / tablets.

App will basicly move files around or delete them. I will gather information about files from MediaStore.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

My question is: Is there any proper / advised method (via MediaStore, for example) to handle the media files, or can / should I just manipulate them via [io/File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class?

Comment: You do not have filesystem-level access to everything that is indexed in the `MediaStore`. For example, on Android 4.4+, the `MediaStore` may contain metadata about images on removable storage that you cannot directly access via the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually predicted that and I will handle it by just ignoring the files from read only folders. I did not included this info in the question to keep it brief.